# Flow to delete files in SharePoint sub folder completes but files not deleted

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-flow, power-automate

I created a Power Automate flow to delete files every 5 minutes from a subfolder in a document library. It runs successfully but does not delete any file. Below are the two flows that I tested, none of them work. Please tell me what needs to be corrected here:
[image]

[image]

Comment: When Flow runs successfully, are you getting correct file array in output of "Filter Array" action? Check run history for previous flow run.

Comment: If it runs without errors, but nothing is deleted, most likely problem source is either in your GetFiles action or Filter array, that results in a zero length set of files to process. When you check the outputs of those steps in history, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use 'List Folder' action:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Flow-to-delete-files-in-SP-sub-folder-completes-but-files-not/m-p/455710/highlight/false#M11406